# Utf-8 encoding blocking console prints

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, tweepy

So because my program was not able to process emojis I set the default encoding to utf-8 by writing

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

in my code but when I did I noticed that the console was not showing any of the prints I had in my program anymore even though everything else besides that worked just fine.

Comment: Your console should also use UTF-8.

Comment: how do I do that?? and what does that have to do with the prints in my program not showing up?

Comment: How should we tell you without any details about the problem, your machine and setup?

Comment: im using windows 10 and python 2.7